# Are Haskell thunks mutable concerning evaluation?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, seq

While looking into parallel programming, and subsequently evaluation strategies, the question whether thunks are mutable came up. To give an example, let's say I have the following code:

```
foo = 1 + 2         -- Thunk
bar = foo `seq` foo -- Evaluates foo
```

Calling `seq` when evaluating `bar` evaluates `foo`, giving `bar` the normal form value `3`. Does this evaluation affect `foo` as well? That is, is the value of `foo` still `1+2` or is it `3` after evaluating `bar`?

Comment: `seq x x` doesn't act like you expect: it is exactly the same as just `x`. (`seq` is a little strange: there is even [an entire article](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Seq) about it on the Haskell wiki.)

Comment: That Wiki entry gives quite a good answer, wish I could upvote it.

Comment: If `foo` is the result of a pure computation, then you'd *want* it to be evaluated at most once, for the sake of efficiency. It turns out that most compilers do what you would want in this case, given that the Haskell report does not specify the exact behavior.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Haskell report only specifies that the evaluation order is ["non-strict"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-strict_semantics#Non-strict_evaluation), so either behavior would conform to the standard.

However, using [lazy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) (["call by need"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-strict_semantics#Call_by_need)) evaluation, which involves sharing values in a way that makes thunks "mutable" as you describe, offers asymptotic improvements over ["call by name"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-strict_semantics#Call_by_name) (that is, no sharing).

So in GHC (and probably most other reasonable implementations), `foo` will become `3` after you force it for the first time. However, this is not mandated by the standard, which you should keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

`foo` and `bar` are [Constant Applicative Forms](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Constant_applicative_form), which (quoting from the link):

> ...can either be compiled to a piece of graph which will be shared by
>   all uses or to some shared code which will overwrite itself with some
>   graph the first time it is evaluated.

The second part of this sentence corresponds to lazy evaluation, where `foo` will be 3 after evaluating `bar`. The first part is more general (doesn't say what happens to the shared piece of graph), so it leaves a possibility for re-evaluation of `foo`.